Using autoscaling docker.machine executor, can't set up docker:dind
Updates (Full initial description below)
Update 1: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
I did not show those log entries initially, but just before starting the dind container i see these log entries:
Using Docker executor with image adoptopenjdk:11-jdk ...
WARNING: Container based cache volumes creation is disabled. Will not create volume for "/cache"
WARNING: Container based cache volumes creation is disabled. Will not create volume for "/certs/client"

This made me try to disable TLS entrirely, by adding the following to my .gitlab-ci.yml
default:
  image: adoptopenjdk:11-jdk
  services:
    - docker:dind

variables:
  # Instruct Testcontainers to use the daemon of DinD.
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  #Disable TLS communication to docker daemon
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  # Improve performance with overlayfs.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

The inclusion of DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "" actually now makes everything work properly!
I don't have the explanation as to why, though. If someone can give me that explanation, I'll happily mark the answer, otherwise I'll add an answer myself.
Update 2: DinD without TLS and docker socket binding
It seems that running docker:dind in giltab-ci is not compatible in my setup, with mounting the docker socket from the host, as the first creates a full docker daemon in a container, and the second tries to allow access to the docker daemon of the host, so we have to choose one.
Thanks to @pierrefaidherbe for making that clear, and pointing to the release that made TLS mandatory for dind (https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/31/docker-in-docker-with-docker-19-dot-03/).
Initial Description
My ultimate purpose is to run a client library's test suite (using TestContainers) with a live API instance pulled from our docker registry. So we have to execute docker pull in the job to fetch the container. This is the recommended way for TestContainers to pull private images, to pre-fetch with docker pull (as far as I know).
We have set up autoscaling docker runners on EC2. It works very well, but I ran into an issue where I need to pull an image from our private ECR registry, inside a job.
The runner manager config.toml is as follows:
# limit of the jobs that can be run concurrently across all runners
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "Build-manager(Instance : i-REDACTED)"
  url = "https://our.gitlab.server/"
  token = "REDACTED"
  token_obtained_at = "REDACTED"
  token_expires_at = "REDACTED"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  # maximum number of machines (running and idle) that this runner will spawn
  limit = 5
  [runners.docker]
    image = "adoptopenjdk:11-jdk"
    privileged = true
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
    tls_verify = false
    
    volumes = [
#              "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock",
               "/cache",
               "/certs/client"
            ]
    
    #disable the Docker executor’s inner cache mechanism since we will use the distributed cache mode
    disable_cache = true
    services_limit = -1
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      BucketName = "our-gitlab-cache-bucket"
      BucketLocation = "REDACTED"
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 1
    IdleTime = 1800
    MaxBuilds = 100
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "ci-build-runner-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
      "amazonec2-region=eu-west-1",
      "amazonec2-zone=a",
      "amazonec2-ami=REDACTED",
      "amazonec2-iam-instance-profile=Build-manager-runner-InstanceProfile",
      "amazonec2-vpc-id=REDACTED",
      "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-REDACTED",
      "amazonec2-private-address-only=true",
      "amazonec2-tags=CostId,Build-Runners,CostIdDetail,Build-Runners.Generic,InstanceType,Gitlab-runner,Project,Build-Runners,runner-manager-name,gitlab-aws-autoscaler",
      "amazonec2-instance-type=m5.xlarge",
      "amazonec2-security-group=Build-manager-runners_ACCESS",
      "amazonec2-request-spot-instance=true",
      "amazonec2-spot-price=0.1",
      "amazonec2-volume-type=gp3",
      "amazonec2-root-size=100",
      "amazonec2-userdata=/etc/gitlab-runner/runner-startup.sh",
      "amazonec2-volume-encrypted=true",
    ]
    [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
      Periods = ["* * * * * mon-fri *"]
      IdleCount = 0
      IdleTime = 1800
      Timezone = "UTC"
    [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
      Periods = ["* * 8-18 * * mon-fri *"]
      IdleCount = 0
      IdleTime = 3600
      Timezone = "UTC"
    [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
      Periods = ["* * * * * sat,sun *"]
      IdleCount = 0
      IdleTime = 1800
      Timezone = "UTC"

Let's see a simplified version of our .gitlab-ci.yml file:
default:
  image: adoptopenjdk:11-jdk
  services:
    - docker:dind

variables:
  # Instruct Testcontainers to use the daemon of DinD.
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  # Improve performance with overlayfs.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  #Keep this up to date
  API_VERSION: v2.1.1

test_only:
  stage: build
  script:
    #install docker,etc
    - ./scripts/bash/install_os_dependencies.sh 
    #install aws-cli
    - ./scripts/bash/install_aws.sh 
#    - echo "PAUSING"
#    - sleep 600
    #pre-fetch the API docker image, so it's available in gradle build for testcontainers
    - ./scripts/bash/pre_fetch_docker_images.sh
    - ./scripts/bash/test.sh

pre_fetch_docker_images.sh contains the following commands:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $PRIVATE_ECR_REGISTRY_URL_BASE

#error out if env var API_VERSION is undefined
: ${API_VERSION:?"Need to set API_VERSION"}

echo "**************************************************************************"
echo "* Using version $API_VERSION for tests"
echo "* Please make sure the environment variable API_VERSION is up to date!"
echo "**************************************************************************"
#pre-fetch the image so that TestContainers does not have to
docker pull $PRIVATE_ECR_REGISTRY_URL_BASE/api:$API_VERSION

When config.toml is set up like this (focus on the docker volumes), then I can see the following logs:
Starting service docker:dind ...
Using locally found image version due to "if-not-present" pull policy
Using docker image sha256:88e4c241e05bc46acc203ff700199934e57307d05a26b5c408e2fba5b99ee178 for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:7ff986c816ccc8af25c9f560ca0cba45de2ca2ea2d7099c63099f5539e0d0359 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running (timeout 30 seconds)...
Using locally found image version due to "if-not-present" pull policy
Using docker image sha256:fd22b579185389e40922764c514a3a996f264479b85877b9392ca2f5039d94fd for adoptopenjdk:11-jdk with digest adoptopenjdk@sha256:0f081fe6de07a0a97d74768f512e2a2f2493cb5f383d7d4fa9f46a6d689b6850 ...
Preparing environment 00:00
Running on runner-zcq4javy-project-494-concurrent-0 via runner-zcq4javy-ci-build-runner-1712671477-f5171009...

You can see that the docker:dind service is started and the CI is proceeding.
when pre_fetch_docker_images.sh is executed, I see the following logs:
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
**************************************************************************
* Using version v2.1.1 for tests
* Please make sure the environment variable API_VERSION is up to date!
*************************************************************************
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

What's peculiar is that the docker login command succeeds, but the docker pull command does not succeed in connecting to the daemon.
If I modify the volumes attached to docker runners in the config.toml file as follows (mounting the docker.sock special file):
    volumes = [
              "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock",
               "/cache",
               "/certs/client"
            ]

Then I see this effect when starting up docker:dind:
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:88e4c241e05bc46acc203ff700199934e57307d05a26b5c408e2fba5b99ee178 for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:7ff986c816ccc8af25c9f560ca0cba45de2ca2ea2d7099c63099f5539e0d0359 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running (timeout 30 seconds)...
*** WARNING: Service runner-zcq4javy-project-494-concurrent-0-72e2651efc1535ef-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-zcq4javy-project-494-concurrent-0-72e2651efc1535ef-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
2024-04-09T17:15:06.149248253Z waiting for TCP connection to 172.17.0.2 on [2375 2376]...
2024-04-09T17:15:06.149382718Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2376...
2024-04-09T17:15:06.149458061Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2375...
2024-04-09T17:15:07.149771628Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2375...
2024-04-09T17:15:07.149794328Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2376...
2024-04-09T17:15:08.150110255Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2375...
2024-04-09T17:15:08.150153846Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2376...
Service container logs:
2024-04-09T17:15:06.499698081Z Certificate request self-signature ok
2024-04-09T17:15:06.499731896Z subject=CN = docker:dind server
2024-04-09T17:15:06.514639701Z /certs/server/cert.pem: OK
2024-04-09T17:15:07.164341862Z Certificate request self-signature ok
2024-04-09T17:15:07.164359294Z subject=CN = docker:dind client
2024-04-09T17:15:07.179270874Z /certs/client/cert.pem: OK
2024-04-09T17:15:07.181725611Z cat: can't open '/proc/net/ip6_tables_names': No such file or directory
2024-04-09T17:15:07.182213651Z cat: can't open '/proc/net/arp_tables_names': No such file or directory
2024-04-09T17:15:07.184062522Z iptables v1.8.10 (nf_tables)
2024-04-09T17:15:07.253190858Z time="2024-04-09T17:15:07.253040060Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
2024-04-09T17:15:07.253842654Z failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy

So the docker:dind service is not starting up.
when the job runs, I can see the following logs:
$ ./scripts/bash/pre_fetch_docker_images.sh
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth": dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.31.0.2:53: no such host

So even the docker login is not suceeding when the docker:dind service is not running.
This seems to be due to the mounting of the docker.sock special file on the docker:dind container.
Bonus:
These are the logs of the docker:dind container when it is setup to start up properly:
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.742248889Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 \"ip: can't find device 'aufs'\\nmodprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory\\n\"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.742278990Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.742416138Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.742435311Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.content.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.742527880Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt\"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.742583398Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin" error="devmapper not configured"
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.742596458Z" level=info msg="metadata content store policy set" policy=shared
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750261307Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler\"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750300776Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.differ.v1.walking\"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750323461Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.lease.v1.manager\"..." type=io.containerd.lease.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750348102Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.streaming.v1.manager\"..." type=io.containerd.streaming.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750371909Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750526792Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups\"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750762774Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v2.task\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750894466Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v2.shim\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750910812Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.sandbox.store.v1.local\"..." type=io.containerd.sandbox.store.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750923657Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.sandbox.controller.v1.local\"..." type=io.containerd.sandbox.controller.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750942770Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750961241Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.content-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.750981835Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751003981Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.images-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751023494Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.introspection-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751043017Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751062786Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751084010Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751118648Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751141720Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751158954Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751179967Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.events\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751199232Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.images\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751220168Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751243364Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751263313Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751288533Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.sandbox-controllers\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751310306Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.sandboxes\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751329237Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751353281Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.streaming\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751383850Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751407966Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.transfer.v1.local\"..." type=io.containerd.transfer.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751433608Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.transfer\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751684149Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.version\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.751845865Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.restart\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.752041985Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp\"..." type=io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.752140429Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp\"..." error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.752272441Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.tracing\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.752382023Z" level=info msg="skipping tracing processor initialization (no tracing plugin)" error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin"
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.752580900Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.752603424Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.nri.v1.nri\"..." type=io.containerd.nri.v1
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.752615609Z" level=info msg="NRI interface is disabled by configuration."
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.752925145Z" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd-debug.sock
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.752996676Z" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.753060550Z" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock
time="2024-04-10T08:13:16.753132170Z" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.035738s"
time="2024-04-10T08:13:17.729206072Z" level=info msg="Setting the storage driver from the $DOCKER_DRIVER environment variable (overlay2)"
time="2024-04-10T08:13:17.729228449Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] trying configured driver: overlay2"
time="2024-04-10T08:13:17.755365665Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2024-04-10T08:13:17.878372710Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
time="2024-04-10T08:13:17.889604357Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=8b79278 containerd-snapshotter=false storage-driver=overlay2 version=26.0.0
time="2024-04-10T08:13:17.889734278Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
time="2024-04-10T08:13:17.930324430Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
time="2024-04-10T08:13:17.930343488Z" level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2376"
2024/04/10 08:13:17 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.3:50382: EOF

Has anyone else achieved my initial goal differently, or solved this issue?

It seems that version 19 of docker has introduced some breaking changes regarding DinD and certificates creation for gitlab CI that could explain why you had to turn off TLS, have a look at this article.
https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/31/docker-in-docker-with-docker-19-dot-03/
